# making a direct phone call using Twilio on Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

i am having an issue making a direct phone call using twilio on Node.js,
bellow is what i have tried

```
...
   client.calls
      .create({
         twiml: '<Response><Dial><+122*********</Dial></Response>',
         to: '+122*********',
         from: '+144444*******'
       })
...
```

with the above code, after i sent the request, the receiver will get a phone call from the sender(+14444****) and once he picked up the call, he will then receive another call from different number so i am a bit confused on what is happening,

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you create the call twice, the first time via the `calls.create()` and then via the TwiML node `<Dial>`. You can remove the Dial node entirely and start right away with the TwiML instructions:

```js
   client.calls
      .create({
         twiml: '<Response> <Say>Hi</Say><Pause length="60" /></Response>',
         to: '+122*********',
         from: '+144444*******'
       })
```

Comment: hi @IObert, thanks for your response, i have updated the code and removed the Dial node, so now once i placed the call and the receiver picked it up the call, its says the wold "Hi".  SO how can the two parties exchange conversation, because everything went silence after the "Hi"

Comment: If you want to connect two persons via Twilio, you need the Dial node. However, the Dial node should then not point to the same phone number that you already used in "from" [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500034/connect-two-persons-through-twilio-client)

Comment: thanks, its seems i will need three different numbers, one for the "To," one for the "From", and another one for the Dial node. but what i want to achieve is that the userA call userB then both can start the conversation immediately.